# How to use REGEXP_REPLACE to remove parameters from function?

Tags: oracle, replace, plsql, parameters, regexp-replace

> > > > [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5vjE.gif)

I have a column that stores C# codes, how do I remove the last 3 parameters of the "FunctionA"? Note that the column contains multiple functions, but I only need to replace "FunctionA" using PL/SQL, I know REGEXP_REPLACE might do the trick, but I can't seem to find a way to match/replace it.

**Before:**

`Test=FunctionA(varID, 1234,"", A.B,"","","last");`

`Test=FunctionA(varID, 9876,"", C.D);`

`Test=FunctionB(varID, 5555,"", E.F,"","","last");`

**After:**

`Test=FunctionA(varID, 1234,"", A.B);`

`Test=FunctionA(varID, 9876,"", C.D);`<- should not affect this

`Test=FunctionB(varID, 5555,"", E.F,"","","last");`<- should not affect this

Comment: I would like to add that the function's parameter values varies for each record, hence I can't use REPLACE function; I need some sort of pattern matching and remove the last 3 parameter for only "FunctionA"

Comment: Please edit your original post and include in plain text the "before" data as shown in the image.  As a rule, never use images as people trying to help cannot copy/paste to get sample data.  Can the string you need to manipulate occur more than once in the chunk of data? Does that data include carriage return/line feeds or is it one long string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding this pattern:

```
(,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*\);)$
```

And then replace with just `);`.  Here is a sample query:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE ('Test=FunctionA(varID, 1234,"", A.B,"","","last");',
        '(,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*\);)$', ');') AS output
FROM dual
WHERE col LIKE 'Test=FunctionA(%'

Test=FunctionA(varID, 1234,"", A.B);
```

### Demo

Edit: I added a `WHERE` clause which checks the function name.

Comment: Thanks its very close, but it's affecting all other functions in record example below...

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('Test=FunctionA(varID, 1234,"", A.B,"","","last"); Test=FunctionB(varID, 1234,"", A.B,"","","last"); ','(,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*\);)$', ');') AS output
FROM dual



how can you target just "FunctionA"?

Comment: @Wakaboom There might be a way to alter the pattern I used in `REGEXP_REPLACE` but honestly I might just add a `WHERE` clause which checks the function name to play it safe.

Comment: Agree the simple WHERE clause suffice, <hit myself in the head>. So far so good, still playing around with the regex which you have giving, yet to resolve in actual environment. Will post a solution once I found it.

Comment: `Will post a solution once I found it` ... I already found it, at least based on your question.  If not, then should edit your question.

Comment: SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE (
    'Test=FunctionA(varID, 1234,"", A.B,"","","last"); Test=FunctionB(varID, 1234,"", A.B,"","","last"); Test=FunctionA(varID, 1234,"", A.B,"","","last");',
    '([FunctionA]\(varID, 1234,"",[^,]A.B,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*\);)', ');') AS output
FROM dual

I'm getting the below which is wrong...
Test=Function); 
Test=FunctionB(varID, 1234,"", A.B,"","","last"); 
Test=Function);

How can I get the below by modifying the above script?..
Test=FunctionA(varID, 1234,"", A.B);
Test=FunctionB(varID, 1234,"", A.B,"","","last"); 
Test=FunctionA(varID, 1234,"", A.B);

Comment: @Wakaboom If I answered the exact question you posed and/or I came very close to what you actually ended up using, then you should mark this answer correct.

Comment: Sure sorry, first time using this website didn't know i had to do that